# Stackoverflow with TCP?

Tags: tcp, buffer

What happens if my program opens a TCP socket but does not read fast enough from it. That is, my program is reading less bytes than clients are writing.

What will happen when the TCP buffer is filled completely? I assume that TCP will not send ACKs back to the clients, thus the clients will (after an ever increasing backoff time) attempt to send again until finally the server socket can accept again some bytes. So I will never loose bytes - unless the clients give up retrying (but then they will know that sending failed). Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TCP features built-in *flow control* signaled by *window size* to the other side. The value tells the sender how many bytes the receiver can buffer. Once that drops to zero the sender cannot send more data and waits until it opens again.

Comment: The server will send a new ACK with an updated window size once space opens up.  However, in order to handle the case where that packet gets lost, clients periodically try to send a single packet of pending data.  If the receive has space, it will ACK the received data (and send back the new window size) and communication resumes.  If the window is still full, no response is sent.